# Represent integer as binary in C

Tags: c, integer, converting, number-systems

To practice my C, I've written a small function in C to display an integer as an 8-bit binary number. Please let me know how to improve this function, and other C-style coding conventions. Thanks!

```
/**
 * Converts an integer to binary.
 * 
 * @param num Integer to convert.
 * 
 * @return c-string.
**/
const char* to_binary(int num) {

    static char binary[10];
    binary[0] = '0';
    binary[1] = 'b';

    int value = 128;
    int number = num;

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        if (number - value >= 0) {
            binary[i] = '1';
            number = number - value;
        } else {
            binary[i] = '0';
        }
        value = value / 2;
    }

    return binary;

}
```

And here's how you call it:

```
int main() {

    const char* result = to_binary(146);

    printf("%s\n", result);

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- More specific types are available for an eight bit number, such as `uint8_t`
- `static` keyword is dangerous (when used as an output buffer) and results in weird behaviour if your method is called twice
- The arithmetic can be replaced with a more simple `&` (bitwise AND)

```
void to_binary(uint8_t x, char *output) {
    *output++ = '0';
    *output++ = 'b';
    for (int mask = 1<<CHAR_BIT-1; mask!=0 ; mask>>=1) {
        *output++ = x & mask ? '1':'0'; 
    }
    *output = 0; // null terminate the string
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `static` makes it only allocate one time. You can see that if you add the line `to_binary(147);` in the main function and print `result` again. It will print something different because the same memory space is used every time.

Comment: `static` isn't weird and dangerous. It means the data is allocated in either .DATA or the .BBS section of the binary, instead of the stack. This means a variable is allocated once, and the value "kept" between calls. It has legitimate uses.

Comment: @AnnoyinC, I think Ted's point is that using `static` storage makes the *function* dangerous and weird.  Users don't expect such a function to be stateful like that.  BTW, C standard says nothing about "segments" - that's a platform-specific mechanism.

Comment: `int total_bits = sizeof(uint8_t)*8;` --> `sizeof(uint8_t)*8` is always 8.

Comment: `2<<i` should be `1<<i` and you need to start from the MSB, `for (int i = total_bits - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)`.

Comment: Instead of counting with `i` and generating the mask on the fly, you can do something like `for (mask = 1 << 7; mask != 0; mask >>=1)`, this is naively more efficient, but the compiler probably does this already at O1 or so.

Comment: Your placement of spaces in the code is strange.

Comment: Minor nit: I prefer the null terminator to be an actual char: `*output = '\0';` I know it compiles the same, but it's more correctly describes the intent.

Comment: The static output array is completely (except for the last byte, which is 0 due to the array being statically allocated) overridden every time the function is called, isn't it? In that case, a static variable is only dangerous in multithreaded programs. That said, static variables have fallen out of favor for exactly that reason, and your inconspicuous little routine, re-used in another environment (Ariane V...), may suddenly fail.

Comment: @Peter even in a single threaded program, you'd need to copy strings out of the way to keep them safe between calls, which causes unnecessary work and might be forgotten about by the programmer

Comment: For the ultimate portability, 8 and 7 are "magic numbers". <limits.h> #defines CHAR_BIT 8 and <values.h> #defines BITSPERBYTE CHAR_BIT (in Linux Mint GCC).

Comment: When you edit to fix a bug in your code, don't leave a wrong copy first.  Future readers don't benefit at all from seeing the `2<<i` version, just delete it.  The edit history is visible if anyone wants to look at it, leave mistakes there, not as the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Bug**

Code attempts to form a *string*. Yet it lacks a terminating *null character* and space for it.

```
// static char binary[10];
static char binary[11];
```

As a `static`, it is initialized to all zeros.   With increased size, an explicit setting of the null character is not needed.

OP's code *undefined behavior* perhaps "works" as a zero may exist just past `binary[10]`.

**Loop Simplification**

Iterate right (most significant) to left (least significant).

```
for (int i = 10; --i >= 2; ) {
  binary[i] = '0' + (num & 1);
  num /= 2;
}
```

**Unclear functionality**

When `num > 255` code prints all `'1'`.
When `num < 0` code prints all `'0'`.

Code should 1) not use an `int` argument or 2) state functionality when `num` is outside the [0-255] range.

**Alternative**

I'd avoid the use of `static` and provide a buffer to the function.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359).

Comment: Just a thought, but it might work with 10 because there could be unused bytes after for alignment.

Comment: @ben Agree.  See "OP's code undefined behavior perhaps "works" as a zero may exist just past binary[10]."

Comment: @Ben even if there are "unused bytes for alignment", there is no guarantee that these bytes are initialized to 0. Still undefined behavior.

Comment: @RolandIllig, hence the `might`.

Comment: @L.F. Agree `static` `char` are zero-initialized. Yet the bytes near, though not part of, `binary[10]` are the issue.  They are not specified to be zero nor even accessible.

Comment: @L.F. OK to delete related comments then.